# CSV column formatting while spooling a csv file in sqlplus

Tags: unix, ksh

How do i extract a number formatted column when i spool to a csv file from unix when the column is varchar in database?

Number format in CSV is 5.05291E+12
should actually be 5052909272618

Comment: Did you open the csv file in MS Excel and saved it? Generally it changes the format.

Comment: This is what bc does: 5.05291*10^12=
5052910000000.00000
You have lost precision, you cannot get it back unless you go to the source that actually shows 5052909272618 to be the value.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not a Unix or ksh problem, but an Excel problem. Assuming Excel is the default application for a .csv file, When you double-click to open in Excel, it makes the column type "General" by default and you get the scientific notation instead of the text value as expected.  If your numeric data has leading zeroes they will be removed also.

One way to fix is to start Excel (this example in the 2010 version), the go to Data/get external data/from text, follow the wizard making sure to set the "column data format" to "text" for the column that contains your large number (click on the column in the "data preview" section first).  Leading zeroes will be preserved also.

You could code a vba macro that would open with all columns as text (a little searching will show you some examples) but there seems to be no place to tell Excel to treat columns as "text" by default.

Answer (score 0):

There was need to develop report and I was also facing the same issue.i found that there is one workaround/solution. e.g.
your table name -->  EMPLOYEE
contains 3 columns colA,colB,colC. the problem is with colB. after connecting to sqlplus you can save the  the data in spool file as :

select colA||  *','''||colB||''','*  ||colC from employee

sample result:

3603342979,*'8938190128981938262'*,142796283 .

when excel opens the file it displays the result "as-it-is"